# How many levels are there in Bejeweled Twist Mobile (in classic mode)?

Tags: bejeweled-twist

How many levels are there in the mobile version of Bejeweled Twist in classic mode?

Comment: In which mode? Classic? Zen?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Classic. Changed question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an email I received from PopCap Customer Support, the levels in Bejeweled Twist in Classic mode should go for for essentially forever as long as you can complete them.